# Issue binding to property of another view model

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-4

I should note that I am using Prism, but that should not be causing my issue. My issue is as follows. I have 2 view models, A and B. B is a "static" view model(ContainerControlledLifetimeManager), and A is a normal view model. A has a reference to B. B does some async tasks and has a List<> of results that A binds to in xaml as follows.

```
    //This is A's view, and B is the reference in A's view model
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding B.CandidateDesignatorList,Mode=TwoWay}"  ....etc>
```

After B's CandidateDesignatorList  has results added to it asynchronously, my ItemsControl doesn't update **UNLESS I do the following.**

```
   B = someunitycontainer.Resolve<B>();
```

So basically, when I look at B in the debugger at this line, I see that CandidateDesignatorList has 3 items, so it is getting the items set, but it wont display anything in my ItemsControl list until I "reset" the connection, even though B is a global static view model.

I think this is an issue with binding, but I don't know what else to try, since i thought setting Mode=TwoWay would make this work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using `List<T>` use `ObservableCollection<T>` which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` which will notify UI in case any item is added/removed from the list.

Comment: To add to @RohitVats suggestion. There is also `BindingList<T>` which has other options.

Comment: Interesting. I changed it to an ObservableCollection, but to no avail. I really thought that was going to work after reading up on it, since that is exactly what I need.

Comment: I did some refactoring and it is working now with the ObservableCollection. Something, somewhere was breaking things, but the ObservableCollection was the key. Thank you all so much!

Comment: Just an FYI, `ItemsSource` should really only use `OneWay` or `OneTime` binding because it is highly unlikely that the UI will be replacing the collection with a brand new one.